# How do I call a Typescript function from HTML (using Parcel)?

Tags: html, typescript, parcel

I'm using Parcel. I'm trying to call a function from a form `oninput` event in HTML.

I keep getting an error that the function is undefined, even though I have the script tag before the form.

I simply run `parcel index.html` to start the webserver with the following code:

```js
export function formInputChanged(input: HTMLInputElement, output: HTMLOutputElement){  
  output.value = input.value;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <script src="./formChanges.ts"></script>
  <form id="input_form">
    <input type="range" name="min_lvr" value="20" min="0.0" max="100" step="1"
      oninput="formInputChanged(this, txt_min_lvr);">
    <output name="txt_min_lvr" for="min_lvr" value="min_lvr.value"></output>%
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I know I can do the update inline in the HTML code, but I would like to know how to do it with an external function.

Answer (score -1):

try binding your function(event handler) to the DOM element directly

```html
<html>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <script src="./formChanges.ts"></script>
  <form id="input_form">
    <input id="range_input" type="range" name="min_lvr" value="20" min="0.0" max="100" step="1"
      oninput="formInputChanged(this, txt_min_lvr);">
    <output name="txt_min_lvr" for="min_lvr" value="min_lvr.value"></output>%
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
export function formInputChanged(input: HTMLInputElement, output: HTMLOutputElement){  
  output.value = input.value;
}

document.querySelector('#range_input').addEventListener('oninput',formInputChanged)
```